# How to tell which selectbox has a changed value using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two selectboxes on a web page.  One displays a monthly report while another displays an archived monthly report.  I would like to set a value to "Current" or "Archived" based on which selectbox is used.  This is what I have done to this point.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sMonth').change(function(){
            <?php $viewType = 'Current'; ?>
        }).change();
        $('#sReportURL').change(function(){
            <?php $viewType = 'Archived'; ?>
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

When I load the page, the value I want does not appear on the web page.  Is there something I am missing to get this value to appear?

Comment: not possible. PHP executes on the server, JS executes on the client, and both execute and entirely different points in time. The php won't even EXIST in the generated html.

Comment: To get this data on your php, you have to use a hidden input, change its value using jQuery according to the selectbox, and the, on submit, see the value of this hidden input... that's the way how HTML / JS / PHP communicate

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax:

```
<div id="report">
</div>
```

and mod the script like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sMonth').change(function(){
            $('#report').load('report.php?viewType=current');
        });
        $('#sReportURL').change(function(){
            $('#report').load('report.php?viewType=archived');
        });
    });
```

and report.php:

```
$viewType = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'viewType');

if($viewType == 'archived'){
echo $archivedReport;
}else{
echo $currentReport;
}
```

Comment: what is(not) happening? What do you see in the network tab of your browsers dev console(hit f12) when changing the select

Comment: When I select a month from the archived report selectbox and then click on the button, I am seeing at the first line /js/MonthlyReports.js,...:89 as the initiator.  When I select a month from the non-archived select box (which changes it automatically, I am seeing /MonthlyReports/view/dealer/:169 as the initiator in the first line.

Comment: look in the network tab, you should be able to open the response and see what is returned by the server, sounds like your looking at the console tab